# what does the regular expression /[^\d|\-+|\.+]/g mean?

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

The following code uses the regular expression `/[^\d|\-+|\.+]/g`.
I want to know how the code works and what the expression does. Can anybody help me?

```
app.$inject = ['$scope'];

app.directive('format', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
  return {
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
        if (!ctrl) return;


        ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function (a) {
            return $filter(attrs.format)(ctrl.$modelValue)
        });


        ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {
            var plainNumber = viewValue.replace(/[^\d|\-+|\.+]/g, '');
            elem.val($filter('number')(plainNumber));
            return plainNumber;
        });
    }
  };
}]);
```

Comment: MDN Reg Exp https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions Learn, look at the chart, piece it together.

Comment: The `|`s and `+`s inside the `[ ]` make it look like it's doing something other than what it's actually doing.

Answer (score 12):

It's always useful to have a tool to test these things. Regex are much harder to read than they are to write.

Here's [a visualization](http://www.regexper.com/#%2F%5B%5E%5Cd%7C%5C-%2B%7C%5C.%2B%5D%2Fg) of how that regex in particular behaves:

[image: regex.png]

`[]` will match one of the characters found in the set, `^` means to match anything *that's not in the set*, and then `\d|\-+|\.+` mean any digit (that's the `\d`), `|`, `-`, `+`, `.`, and a couple characters that were repeated.

Also, for a basic understanding of regex you might want to [check out this blog post](http://blog.ponyfoo.com/2013/05/27/learn-regular-expressions).

Comment: Interesting tool, didn't realize something like this even existed.